# php is / switch statement check with '0' string or '00' string

Tags: php

I have an idiot question but I'm stuck.

here is my simply code

```
$my_string = '00';

switch ((string)$my_string)
{
    case '-1': $return_string = 'bla bla..'; break;
    case '0': $return_string = 'One zero'; break;
    case '00': $return_string = 'Double zero'; break;
    default: $return_string = 'default'; break;
}

echo $return_string;
```

The result of the code before returns

```
One Zero
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: This is very common source of errors in PHP.  What might be even more surprising is the fact that `("0xFF"==255) => True`

Comment: "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value." - [PHP Spec](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
this is basically because php is not a strongly type language.
so "00" == "0" gives true (and as said switch uses the equality operator)

you might change this to if else statements with triple equals and that would do it.

"00" === "0" gives false. check this thread for more details. [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

Answer (score 4):

`switch` uses [equality](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose), not identity. Since `'0'` equals `'00'` (in that they both evaluate to `0`), the structure won't work.

Comment: Is there eny way to check that ? I have try both switch and if statements but the result its the same

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above: switch doesn't check for identical type and value (difference between `==` and `===`). To get a switch working in your case, you could do this:

```
$my_string = '00';
switch (true)
{
    case ((string) $my_string === '-1'): $return_string = 'bla bla..'; break;
    case ((string) $my_string === '0'): $return_string = 'One zero'; break;
    case ((string) $my_string === '00'): $return_string = 'Double zero'; break;
    default: $return_string = 'default'; break;
}
```

Comment: This is rather obtuse and it'd probably be more readable simply to use `if` clauses instead.

Comment: as far as readability is concerned, I agree. But since I don't know what the OP is actually trying to do, I wouldn't go as far as to suggest `if` branching, since `switch` has the benefit of fall-through (I consider it to be a benefit, at least) and, when dealing with 10+ cases, it dramatically improves readability, IMO. Even in this case. I must admit, it would be more readible to convert `$my_string` to a string beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
switch ('_'.$my_string)
{
    case '_-1': $return_string = 'bla bla..'  ; break;
    case '_0' : $return_string = 'One zero'   ; break;
    case '_00': $return_string = 'Double zero'; break;
    default   : $return_string = 'default'    ; break;
}
```