# php Switch statement and 0

Tags: php, switch-statement, zero

Hi i see a code today like that

```
$i=0;
switch($i){
    case 'TEST': print "Test";break;
    case 0: print "0";break;
}
```

The normal output seems to be `0` but it prints `Test`. Then i try to understand it and got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959160/php-is-switch-statement-check-with-0-string-or-00-string). That is, when compare a number with string then string will convert to number and comparison performed numerically. OK then its ok to get the output `Test`.

But what if i set identical to it like

```
$i=0;
switch($i){
    case ($a === 'Test'): print "Text";break;
    case ($a === 0): print "0";break;
}
```

That also give the result `Test` so i am confused here. And if i use `==` instead of `===` then it show blank. So please clear me that.

Comment: use `switch(true)` as $a==='Test' equates to true or false

Comment: You're going to get loose typing comparison for the cases in the switch statement - `0 !== 'Test'` but `0 == 'Test'` - so it's best avoiding mixing different datatypes

Comment: Also the first example 0 compared to 'TEST' - 'TEST' is a string which equates to 0 causing a match http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php `===` does type matching too

Comment: OK i got it guys. I have to use `switch(true)` for comparison. Thanks `Waygood` for your answer.

Comment: $a==='Test' equates to false. Switch(0) is the same as give me first case where its FALSE, as 0 IS false.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to make $i as numeric?
Let it be string too...

```
$i="0";
switch($i){
    case 'Test': print "Text";break;
    case '0': print "0";break;
}
```

That prints 0...

Answer (score 0):

Switch treats `0` as `false` so here you can go:

```
$i=0;
switch(true){
    case $i === 'TEST': print "Test";
        break;
    case $i === 0 : print "0";
        break;
}
```